# New blank tab opening unwantedly

Tags: jquery

I am trying to download pdf file using below code.

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/test.pdf";
```

This will be placed in ajax success result.
It downloaded file properly but opened unwanted blank page in new tab.
Do any one faced this issue.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

I have tried even `window.open(url,"_self")` along with name attribute.

But not working.

Comment: Instead of `window`, did you try to use `document.location` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. but not working

Comment: When I have this kind of "behavior", I use an hidden link on which I change the `href` attribute and simulate a click on link.

Answer (score 0):

have small idea.Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function openPdf(e, path, redirect) { 
    e = e || window.event; // for IE
    e.preventDefault();   
    window.open(path, 'somename', ... /* options */); 
    // redirect current page to new location
    window.location = redirect;
 } 
</script>
```

html:

```
<a href="files/pdf/a_pdf_doc.pdf"
onclick="openPdf(event, 'files/pdf/a_pdf_doc.pdf', 'newpage.html');">
PDF Doc
</a>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using windown.open and as well as window.location.